# Core-Data: How to set up relationship from one object to specific one in many objects with same name?

Tags: iphone, core-data, entity-relationship

I have a question in core data:

there are 2 Entities in the project, `Books` and `Pages`; 
there are 3 Objects `book`s user created in Entity `Books`; 
there are several Objects `page`s user created in Entity `Pages`;
relationship inbetween is one `page` belongs to one `book`, one `book` has many pages.

and my question: there are 3 `book` with the same object name "book",and each has unique attribute `.bookName` : `@"metal"` ;`@"plastic"` ;`@"glass"`. how to set `page` to the `book` with `.bookName = @"glass"` ?

```
    //In BookViewController
    Books *book = (Books *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Books" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    //textView.text is user input text
    book.bookName = textView.text;


    //In PageViewController
    Pages *page = (Pages *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Pages" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    page.itsbook = WHAT?
```

Thank you for reading, I stuck here like: a day, really appreciate your help, love you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to find a specific book then you need to use a `NSFetchRequest` to ask Core data for it.

Quite some code is needed, so you probably add a convinience method to your `Book`class that looks something like this:

```
+(Book*)bookWithName:(NSString*)name
{
    // 0. I assume you have something like this to get the context…
    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [NSManagedObjectContext threadLocalContext];

    // 1. Create an empty request
    NSFetchRequest* request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

    // 2. Set the entity description for the object to fetch
    NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Book"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    // 3. Set a predicate asking for objects with a mathing bookName property
    NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE[cd] %@", 
                                                              @"bookName",
                                                              name];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    // 4. Execute the request on the managed object context.
    NSArray* objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL];

    // 5. Result is an array, maybe handle empty array and many objects?
    return [objects lastObject];
 }
```

Comment: Great! never thought this before, after this method, the object book with .bookName=@"glass" is in the array, next is "for (NSManagedObject *book in objects) {page.itsbook = book;}" this statement sets the page to the @"glass"book from PeyloW's Fetch, that's it! thank you very much, I will test it later. referenced from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383598/core-data-quickest-way-to-delete-all-instances-of-an-entity

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean. If you want to insert a page as a subset of the book you want this line of code:

```
[book addPageToBookObject:page]; // the method will be the relationship name
```

If you want to get the book from the page object you'll need an inverse relationship from the pages to the book.

Comment: thank you, Thomas, [book addPageToBookObject:page]; is good to set, but there are 3 "book" objects in Entity: book.bookName=@"metal"; book.bookName=@"plastic"; book.bookName=@"glass", want to set "page" to the @"glass" one.