# Deleting entity aborts the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am using core data to store some details. But when I run my app for the second time the contents in the entity gets doubled. and this continues each time I run my app. I tried to delete the objects before I add like this question [Core Data: Quickest way to delete all instances of an entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383598/core-data-quickest-way-to-delete-all-instances-of-an-entity) but then the deletion works successfully not the addition part and hence am getting quit in the code (from some other part from where I am accessing the Data base)

I used the below code

```
-(void)synDBFavSpecies:(NSString *)speciesName:(NSString *)speciesId:(NSString *)Imagename
{ 
    NSManagedObjectContext *context=app.managedObjectContext; 
    NSError *err;

    NSFetchRequest *request1=[[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity1=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FavoriteSpecies" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request1 setEntity:entity1];
    NSArray *result1=[context executeFetchRequest:request1 error:&err];
    NSManagedObject *ph1;
    for(ph1 in result1 )
    {
        [context deleteObject:ph1];
        NSString *sid= [ph1 valueForKey:@"ID"]; 
        NSLog(@"Sp.ID:%@",sid);

        if(sid)
        {

            [context deleteObject:ph1];
            if(![context save:&err])
            {
                NSLog(@"error");
            }
        }
    }

    NSManagedObject *SetDB=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FavoriteSpecies" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [SetDB setValue:speciesName forKey:@"favspecies"];
    [SetDB setValue:speciesId forKey:@"ID"];
    [SetDB setValue:Imagename forKey:@"speciesimage"];

    if(![context save:&err])
    {
         NSLog(@"error");
    }
}
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: if i comment the deletion part it works fine. but each time the content gets doubled. when i include deletion only deletion works not addition. so DB becomes empty.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve in `for` loop

Comment: It would be easier to guess the cause of the problem if you gave information about the error.  Use @try/@catch around the code that's failing and log the exception description and it's callStackSymbols.

Comment: @samfisher I think the `for` loop allows him to delete duplicates. But I think it could be cleaner to do what I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i made a mistake in my code. The above code was running in aloop. so when i deleted it the insertion was not performing. So i made another method to delete the database and called that method before calling this one. Hence got it working.

Answer (score 0):

priya,

First of I would change the

```
NSLog(@"error");
```

with a more detail description for the error like:

```
NSLog(@"My save failed: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
```

Then, does your `FavoriteSpecies` entity has other relationships with other entitites?

If you want to prevent duplicates you need to handle it in a different way. For example, if your `ID` is the identifier for your `FavoriteSpecies` entity, you could set up a fetch request with a predicate and see what it returns. For example:

```
NSFetchRequest *request1 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
[request1 setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FavoriteSpecies" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
[request1 setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ID == %@", speciesID]];
[request1 setFetchLimit:1]; // it's not necessary to do it since the ID is unique
```

If you execute the fetch, you will retrieve one or zero objects (if `ID` is unique)

```
NSArray *result1 = [context executeFetchRequest:request1 error:&err];
if([result1 count] == 0) {
    // insert here since you haven't that object
} else { 
    // do what you want, for example updating
}
```

Setting up a predicate is equal to adding the `WHERE` clause in a `SELECT` statement.

Hope that helps.

Comment: not sure where i went wrong. I added the deleting code to some other part of my code and now its working fine. thank you very much

Comment: @priya You're welcome. If my asnwer was useful upvote it (if you want). In addition, post your solution as an answer and mark it as answered. Thank you. Cheers.