# Delete all items in a for each loop?

Tags: ios, swift, foreach, swiftui

I have a fetch request, and a foreach loop listing out the items. How can I write a function to delete all items in this set?

```
@FetchRequest(
    entity: TaskItem.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \TaskItem.completedDate, ascending: false)],
    predicate: NSPredicate(format: "isComplete == %@", NSNumber(value: true))
) var taskItems: FetchedResults<TaskItem>
```

```
ForEach(taskItems, id: \.self) { item in
    Text("\(item.title)")
}
```

I have this function to delete individual items. Can this code be tweaked and used to delete all items?

```
func deleteTask(indexSet: IndexSet) {
    let source = indexSet.first!
    let taskItem = taskItems[source]
    managedObjectContext.delete(taskItem)
    saveTasks()
}
```

Comment: What _all_ elements? All in the set or all objects that you have fetched? Either way you should look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560900/coredata-delete-multiple-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over `taskItems` and delete `taskItem` one-by-one:

```
func deleteAllTasks() {
    for taskItem in taskItems {
        managedObjectContext.delete(taskItem)
    }
    saveTasks()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
func deleteAll() {
    // for each taskItem... delete
    taskItems.forEach(managedObjectContext.delete)
    saveTasks()
}
```

Assuming `saveTasks` saves the `managedObjectContext` object.