# Delete ALL Core Data Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am a little confused as to how to delete all core data in swift. I have created a button with an `IBAction` linked. On the click of the button I have the following:

```
let appDel: foodforteethAppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as foodforteethAppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
```

Then I've messed around with various methods to try and delete all the core data content but I can't seem to get it to work. I've used removeAll to delete from a stored array but still can't delete from the core data. I assume I need some type of for loop but unsure how to go about making it from the request.

I have tried applying the basic principle of deleting a single row

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

    let appDel: foodforteethAppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as foodforteethAppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {

        if let tv = tblTasks {
            context.deleteObject(myList[indexPath!.row] as NSManagedObject)
            myList.removeAtIndex(indexPath!.row)
            tv.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        }

        var error: NSError? = nil
        if !context.save(&error) {
            abort()
        }

    }

}
```

However, the issue with this is that when I click a button, I don't have the indexPath value and also I need to loop through all the values which I can't seem to do with context.

Comment: Well show us some of the various methods you've tried in Swift and maybe we can help you. In terms of APIs and How to do this, that question answers it all and you should just be doing the exact same thing, just in Swift.

Comment: Question is already answered here in more efficient way - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383598/core-data-quickest-way-to-delete-all-instances-of-an-entity?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Core Data: Quickest way to delete all instances of an entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383598/core-data-quickest-way-to-delete-all-instances-of-an-entity)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have got it working using the following method:

```
@IBAction func btnDelTask_Click(sender: UIButton){

    let appDel: foodforteethAppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as foodforteethAppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext  
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Food")

    myList = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)


    if let tv = tblTasks {

        var bas: NSManagedObject!

        for bas: AnyObject in myList
        {
           context.deleteObject(bas as NSManagedObject)
        }

        myList.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        tv.reloadData()
        context.save(nil)
    }
}
```

However, I am unsure whether this is the best way to go about doing it. I'm also receiving a 'constant 'bas' inferred to have anyobject' error - so if there are any solutions for that then it would be great

**EDIT**

Fixed by changing to bas: AnyObject

Answer (score 66):

**Try this simple solution:**

```
func deleteAllData(entity: String)
{
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity)
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do 
    {
        let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        for managedObject in results
        {
            let managedObjectData:NSManagedObject = managedObject as! NSManagedObject
            managedContext.deleteObject(managedObjectData)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Detele all data in \(entity) error : \(error) \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

**Swift 4**

```
func deleteAllData(_ entity:String) {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entity)
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        let results = try dataController.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        for object in results {
            guard let objectData = object as? NSManagedObject else {continue}
            dataController.viewContext.delete(objectData)
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("Detele all data in \(entity) error :", error)
    }
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
 self.deleteAllData("your_entityName")
```

Comment: Incorrect Answer: Delete core data doesn't mean that it will contain only single entity

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier 'dataController'; did you mean 'tabBarController'?

Answer (score 43):

You can use `destroyPersistentStore` starting in **iOS 9.0** and **Swift 3**:

```
public func clearDatabase() {
    guard let url = persistentContainer.persistentStoreDescriptions.first?.url else { return }
    
    let persistentStoreCoordinator = persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator

     do {
         try persistentStoreCoordinator.destroyPersistentStore(at:url, ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, options: nil)
         try persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: nil)
     } catch {
         print("Attempted to clear persistent store: " + error.localizedDescription)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 25):

To Delete all data you can use NSBatchDeleteRequest

```
func deleteAllData(entity: String)
{
    let ReqVar = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity)
    let DelAllReqVar = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: ReqVar)
    do { try ContxtVar.executeRequest(DelAllReqVar) }
    catch { print(error) }
}
```

Comment: Getting error. Delete rule is not supported for batch delete

Answer (score 13):

For `Swift 3.0`

```
func DeleteAllData(){


    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let DelAllReqVar = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Entity"))
    do {
        try managedContext.execute(DelAllReqVar)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 5.1**

Most of the posts here suggests to create a function to delete all entities by *name* and then delete all your entities one by one. like so :

```
resetEntity(named: "MyEntity1")
resetEntity(named: "MyEntity2")
resetEntity(named: "MyEntity3")
...
```

**But** if the real question is how to clean ALL CoreData entity in one go, I suggest you loop over entity names:

```
// Supposing this is a CoreDataController/CoreDataStack class where you have access to `viewContext` and `persistantContainer`
// Otherwise just pass the `persistantContainer` as a parameter, from which you can also retrieve the `viewContext` 
func resetAllCoreData() {

     // get all entities and loop over them
     let entityNames = self.persistentContainer.managedObjectModel.entities.map({ $0.name!})
     entityNames.forEach { [weak self] entityName in   
        let deleteFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)
        let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: deleteFetch)

        do {
            try self?.context.execute(deleteRequest)
            try self?.context.save()
        } catch {
            // error
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this can help

Answer (score 8):

Here is my implementation to clear all core data in Swift 3, based on Jayant Dash's excellent (and comprehensive) answer.  This is simpler due to only supporting iOS10+.  It deletes all core data entities, without having to hardcode them.

```
public func clearAllCoreData() {
    let entities = self.persistentContainer.managedObjectModel.entities
    entities.flatMap({ $0.name }).forEach(clearDeepObjectEntity)
}

private func clearDeepObjectEntity(_ entity: String) {
    let context = self.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let deleteFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entity)
    let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: deleteFetch)

    do {
        try context.execute(deleteRequest)
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print ("There was an error")
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need context.save()

Answer (score 6):

**In Swift 3.0**

```
 func deleteAllRecords() {
        //delete all data
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let deleteFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "YourClassName")
        let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: deleteFetch)

        do {
            try context.execute(deleteRequest)
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print ("There was an error")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

**For Swift 4.0** (modified version of [svmrajesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33931528/1032372)… or at least what Xcode turned it into before it would run it for me.)

```
func deleteAllData(entity: String) {
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entity)
fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

do
{
    let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    for managedObject in results
    {
        let managedObjectData:NSManagedObject = managedObject as! NSManagedObject
        managedContext.delete(managedObjectData)
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Delete all data in \(entity) error : \(error) \(error.userInfo)")
}
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
deleteAllData(entity: "entityName")
```

Answer (score 4):

In Swift UI

when you select core data at the beginning of project the persistence coordinator is automatically created by swift in app delegate. The scene delegate creates @environmentObject for managed context

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

let contentView = ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
```

create instance of manageObjectContext in content view and also fetchRequest object using property wrapper @FetchRequest

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
@FetchRequest(entity: EntityName.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var entityNames: FetchedResults<EntityName>
```

For delete action perform

```
for entityName in entityNames {
moc.delete(entityName)
}
try? moc.save()
```

try operation can throw error so please implement do try catch block in production code to handle error properly.

Answer (score 3):

This clean() method will fetch entities list from DataModel and clear all data.

```
func deleteAll(entityName: String) -> Error? {
            if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                do {
                    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)
                    let batchDeleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
                    try context.execute(batchDeleteRequest)
                } catch {
                    return error
                }
                return nil
            } else {
                let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)
                fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
                do
                {
                    let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
                    for managedObject in results
                    {
                        if let managedObjectData:NSManagedObject = managedObject as? NSManagedObject {
                            context.delete(managedObjectData)
                        }
                    }
                } catch  {
                    return error
                }
                return nil
            }
        }

        var objectModel: NSManagedObjectModel? {
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                return persistentContainer.managedObjectModel
            } else {
                return persistentStoreCoordinator?.managedObjectModel
            }
        }

        open func clean() {
            if let models = objectModel?.entities {
                for entity in models {
                    if let entityName = entity.name {
                        _ = deleteAll(entityName: entityName)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5.1

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)
let batchDeleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)

        do {
            try coreDataManager.managedObjectContext.execute(batchDeleteRequest)
        } catch {
            print("Detele all data in \(entityName) error :", error)
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two simple methods as far as i know  , first

Method 1:

## Fetch, Delete, Repeat

// Initialize Fetch Request

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Item")
```

// Configure Fetch Request

```
 fetchRequest.includesPropertyValues = false

do {

let items = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]

for item in items {
    managedObjectContext.deleteObject(item)
}

// Save Changes
try managedObjectContext.save()

} catch {
// Error Handling
// ...
```

}

Methode 2:

## Batch Delete Request

// Create Fetch Request

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Item")
```

// Create Batch Delete Request

```
     let batchDeleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
       do {
          try managedObjectContext.executeRequest(batchDeleteRequest)

          } catch {
// Error Handling
    }
```

I have tested both and they both work fine

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

```
func deleteAllData(entity: String){

guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entity)
fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

do {
    let arrUsrObj = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    for usrObj in arrUsrObj as! [NSManagedObject] {            
        managedContext.delete(usrObj)
    }
   try managedContext.save() //don't forget
    } catch let error as NSError {
    print("delete fail--",error)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

To delete all entries in Core Data I have found 2 ways of doing it

1 - With a `for` func

```
func deleteEntries() {
    do {
        let managedObjectContext = try CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.getContext()
        for record in records {
            managedObjectContext.delete(record)
        }
        try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

2 - With a `NSBatchDeleteRequest`

```
func deleteEntries() {
    do {
        let managedObjectContext = try CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.getContext()
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Location")
        let request: NSBatchDeleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
        try managedObjectContext.execute(request)
        try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

I recommend using number 2 because is a better way of handling resources in your app

Answer (score 1):

An alternative can be to completely remove and recreate persistent store (iOS 10+, swift 3).

```
let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask);
    var dbUrl = urls[urls.count-1];
    dbUrl = dbUrl.appendingPathComponent("Application Support/nameOfYourCoredataFile.sqlite")
    do {
        try persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator.destroyPersistentStore(at: dbUrl, ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, options: nil);
    } catch {
        print(error);
    }
    do {
        try persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: dbUrl, options: nil);
    } catch {
        print(error);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to above but with AppDelegte call taken out and UIView variable used

```
var context: NSManagedObjectContext?
//deleting Message

func deleteMessages(entity: String) {
   do {
      let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity)
      print(request)

      if let result = try context!.executeFetchRequest(request) as? [your class of NSManagedObject] {
          for message in result {
             context!.deleteObject(message)
             try context!.save()
             print(message)
             self.tableView.reloadData()
          }
      }
   } catch {
         print("miss")
   }
}
```

**To use call function**

```
self.deleteMessages("TimeMaster")
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this one for delete all the core data entities in Swift3

```
func deleteAllCD(){
    for entityName in ["EntityName", "AnotherEntityName"]{
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)
        let delAllReqVar = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: request)
        do { try persistentContainer.viewContext.execute(delAllReqVar) }
        catch { print(error) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Delete rule is not supported for batch delete

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

```
// Replace 'MyEntityName' with your managed object class.
let moc = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<MyEntityName> = MyEntityName.fetchRequest()
fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
moc.perform {
    do {
        let myEntities = try fetchRequest.execute()
        for myEntity in myEntities {
            moc.delete(myEntity)
        }
        try moc.save()
    } catch let error {
        print("Delete Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func deleteAllData(entity: String)
{
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let ReqVar = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity)
    let DelAllReqVar = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: ReqVar)
    do { try ContxtVar.executeRequest(DelAllReqVar) }
    catch { print(error) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4 :**

**destroyPersistentStoreAtURL(_:withType:options:)** will delete (or truncate) the target persistent store. This will safely destroy a persistent store.

**Add:**

```
do {
    try persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: persistentStoreURL, options: nil)
} catch {
    // Error Handling
}
```

**Destroy / Delete / Truncate:**

```
do {
    try persistentStoreCoordinator.destroyPersistentStoreAtURL(persistentStoreURL, withType: NSSQLiteStoreType, options: nil)
} catch {
    // Error Handling
}
```

Note : Parameters in above method should be identical to addPersistentStoreWithType method. **You need to re-initiate storeCoordinator to use store again.**

Comment: Doesn't seem to actually delete the database file itself, I needed to also call `FileManager.default.removeItem(at: )`.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 4.0

```
  func deleteAllData(_ entity:String) {

    let managedContext =  DatabaseController.getContext().persistentStoreCoordinator
     let context = DatabaseController.getContext()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entity)
    let batchDeleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
    do {
        try managedContext?.execute(batchDeleteRequest, with: context)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 4

From iOS 9, there is the possibility of erasing persistent storage.
For better maintenance – create **NSPersistentStoreCoordinator** extension with **abstract** function.

```
extension NSPersistentStoreCoordinator {
    func destroyPersistentStore(type: String) -> NSPersistentStore? {
        guard 
            let store = persistentStores.first(where: { $0.type == type }),
            let storeURL = store.url 
        else {
            return nil
        }

        try? destroyPersistentStore(at: storeURL, ofType: store.type, options: nil)

        return store
    }
}
```

Then destroying SQLite persistent storage looks pretty simple:

```
let coordinator = persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator
let store = coordinator.destroyPersistentStore(type: NSSQLiteStoreType)
```

---

#### Recommendations

1. Update **destroyPersistentStore** function which is no-nullable and throws specific errors, for example **CoreDataError** enum.
2. Probably you want to refresh your persistent storage. For this, you can use **addPersistentStore** function of *NSPersistentStoreCoordinator*, with retrieved *NSPersistentStore* object from **destroyPersistentStore**.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution for Swift 5 & SwiftUI:**

```
let fetchRequest = DataModel.fetchRequest()
let items = try? viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
for item in items ?? [] {
    viewContext.delete(item)
    }
try? viewContext.save()
```

Here `DataModel` is your model name. You have to pass viewContext:

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
```

Answer (score -1):

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

```
        guard editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete else { return }
        people.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).