# How to delete specific entity data from core data in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, entity-framework, core-data

I have one entity named `Register` with several attributes. I want to delete all the data from the specific entity.

Please give me an answer related to iOS Swift.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658641/delete-all-core-data-swift   .    i tried all stackoverflow code related to delete entity.. & once again answers not find

Answer (score 1):

I've also searched the same and found some like below. Using a Fetch Request to Collect all objects and delete one by one.

```
var arr: [AnyObject] = managedObjContextIns.executeFetchRequest(fetchReq, error: &error)
for managedObj: NSManagedObject in arr 
{
  managedObjContextIns.deleteObject(managedObj)
}
var error: NSErrorPointer? = nil
managedObjContextIns.save(&error)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for giving answer.  but i need answer in swift language. please give me answer in swift @Balaji

Comment: Upvoted :) Good solution. I would check the error at the end, and also instead of `var arr: [AnyObject]`, I would cast it to the type of entity it is, e.g. Register (assuming that register inherits from NSManagedObject)

Comment: thank you for giving answer in swift @BalajiRamakrishnan