# Completely Reset CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, core-data

I am completely at this and out of ideas for about a week now.

I have a CoreData stack with multiple coordinators and managed contexts, and I am attempting to implement a ***logout*** feature in the app.

The tableviews that interact with CoreData is inside a TabBarController, and there are on-boarding (i.e. registration & login) NavigationControllers and ViewControllers that lead up to it.

What I am attempting to implement is a logout (i.e. unwind to initial ViewController. I have tried so far - to no avail:

- reset() each managedObjectContext individually
- every possible combination of tableView.beginUpdates(), tableView.endUpdates(), tableView.reloadData(), frc.performFetch()
- Delete each entity in each managedObject then reset() each managedObjectContext individually
- set tableView, fetchedResultsController delegates and datasource to nil, then to self on viewDidLoad()
- Having a NSNotification that fires just before logging out - deleting everything in CoreData and saving it, effectively updating and emptying the table.
- a whole lot more

Is there a way to **completely** reset CoreData so when the user unwinds to initial ViewController and re-run the whole process I won't get

> Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data
>   change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of
>   NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  attempt to insert
>   row 9 into section 0, but there are only 9 rows in section 0 after the
>   update with userInfo (null)

or in the case I emptied the table via Notifications:

> Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data
>   change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of
>   NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  attempt to insert
>   row 9 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the
>   update with userInfo (null)

CoreData works ***just fine*** if I logout, close the app, and restart. No errors this way. This makes me think there is a way to completely reset CoreData (and any tableViews, fetchedResultsControllers associated with it) or reset to a pristine state when unwinding to the initial ViewController.

*or should I just duplicate the storyboard and have a separate set of on-boarding viewControllers just for logging out so CoreData doesn't reinitialize?*

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Hii... I am clear lil bit about your problem , are you willing to reset core-data when you logout from app and when you login the whole process for core-data take place with initial level ?

Am i assuming right ?

Comment: Did you try this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658641/ios-delete-all-core-data-swift

Comment: @Anita yes that is correct! I am looking to *completely* destroy and nuke CoreData if you will, not just individual entires. The tableviews somehow persists despite logout(unwind), batch delete requests, and context resets.

Comment: Please check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383598/core-data-quickest-way-to-delete-all-instances-of-an-entity

Comment: Above link might helpful to you

Comment: @Anita I checked and no it didn't. Does not work. I have tried NSBatchDeleteRequest many times and it's still giving me the same error. Restarting the app works fine tho.

Comment: Do you have any sample project ? If yes then you can share will try it out at my side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS9 and above you can use `destroyPersistentStore` and optionally add a new one

```
func destroyAllData(storeType : String = NSSQLiteStoreType) throws {
    guard let storeURL = persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.last?.url else {
        print("Missing store URL")
        return
    }
    try persistentStoreCoordinator.destroyPersistentStore(at: storeURL, ofType: storeType)
    // try persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: storeType, configurationName: nil, at: storeURL)
}
```

Comment: Thank lord you're a savior! Extended this to work on multiple stores/coordinators, re-add the sqlite stores and it worked like magic! Why I haven't realized this is beyond disbelief!

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
  static let moduleName = "moduleName"

        //Model
        lazy var managedObjectModel:NSManagedObjectModel = {
            let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: moduleName, withExtension: "momd")!
            return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
        }()

     func deleteAllEntities() {
            let entities = managedObjectModel.entities
            for entity in entities {
                delete(entityName: entity.name!)
            }
        }

func delete(entityName: String) {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)
        let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
        do {
            try persistentStoreCoordinator.execute(deleteRequest, with: DataCoordinator.shared.managedObjectContext)
            debugPrint("Deleted Entitie - ", entityName)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            debugPrint("Delete ERROR \(entityName)")
            debugPrint(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This deletes only entities. What I was looking for was to completely nuke the sqlite store.