# How to delete all data from core data when persistentContainer is not in App delegate method in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am new in Swift and I want to delete all data from core data. I have seen several examples but in all of them `persistentContainer` is in `AppDelegate` and in my case `persistentContainer` is not in `AppDelegate`. It is in a different class as shown below:

```
class CoreDataStack: NSObject {
    
    static let sharedInstance = CoreDataStack()
    private override init() {}
    
    func applicationDocumentsDirectory() {
        if let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last {
            print(url.absoluteString)
        }
    }
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
       
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Database")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
            print(storeDescription)
            
        })
        return container
    }()
    
    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support
    
    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the AppDelegate method I am just calling it as

```
CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.applicationDocumentsDirectory()

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.saveContext()
    }
```

I tried [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658641/ios-delete-all-core-data-swift) but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the solutions can be to use `NSBatchDeleteRequest` for all entities in the persistentContainer. You can add these methods to your `CoreDataStack`:

```
func deleteAllEntities() {
    let entities = persistentContainer.managedObjectModel.entities
    for entity in entities {
        delete(entityName: entity.name!)
    }
}

func delete(entityName: String) {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)
    let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
    do {
        try persistentContainer.viewContext.execute(deleteRequest)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        debugPrint(error)
    }
}
```

The whole code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/bishalg/0390007d52963a180eafd3120012c8e1)

Comment: How can I used this?

Comment: showing used of Use of unresolved identifier 'managedObjectModel' Use of unresolved identifier 'persistentStoreCoordinator'

Comment: showing this error Value of type 'NSPersistentContainer' has no member 'execute'

Comment: How can I call this method where I need. And How to pass entity name in it

Comment: You can call it from anywhere in your project: `CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.deleteAllEntities()`

Comment: It will delete whole database?

Comment: Yes, isn't it what you asked: `How to delete all data from core data`?

Comment: correct but what if I only want to delete single entity.

Comment: Then if your entityName is `SomeModel` you can do: `CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.delete(entityName: "SomeModel")`

Comment: perfect thanks a lot you save my day. Really thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Need to use **NSBatchDeleteRequest** for particular entity from **persistentContainer**

```
func deleteEntityData(entity : String) {
        let deleteFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entity)
        let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: deleteFetch)
        do {
            try CoreDataStack.sharedStack.mainContext.execute(deleteRequest)
            CoreDataStack.sharedStack.saveMainContext()
        } catch {
            print ("There was an error")
        }
}
```

I have detailed an answer in below link.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017449/swift-3-core-data-delete-object/73261963#73261963)

Answer (score 1):

A more radical approach is to remove/recreate your persistent stores.

```
extension NSPersistentContainer {
    func destroyPersistentStores() throws {
        for store in persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores {
            let type = NSPersistentStore.StoreType(rawValue: store.type)
            try persistentStoreCoordinator.destroyPersistentStore(at: store.url!, type: type)
        }
        loadPersistentStores()
    }
    
    func loadPersistentStores() {
        loadPersistentStores { _, error in
            if let error { fatalError(error.localizedDescription) }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage: `try container.destroyPersistentStores()`

[Source](https://www.advancedswift.com/batch-delete-everything-core-data-swift/#delete-everything-delete-all-objects-reset-core-data)