# Using the new Core Data Batch Updates, is it possible to batch delete?

Tags: core-data, ios8

My current method of deleting all of a certain kind of object in Core Data is to [iterate over each object and delete manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1383645/998117), which is rather expensive.

Using the [new batch updates](http://matthewmorey.com/core-data-batch-updates/) added to Core Data this year, can it be accomplished like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible at this time in OS X 10.10/iOS 8.

An `NSBatchUpdateRequest`is only limited to update selected properties. More information on this can be found in [this blog post](http://thermal-core.com/2014/06/14/in-defense-of-core-data-part-II.html#batching) (see the "Deleting a lot of Objects: Not a Problem" section).

Answer (score 5):

Finally you can, in the new WWDC apple introduced `NSBatchDeleteRequest`([wwdc 2015](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=220))