# Deleting All Data in Entity (Core Data) Doesn't Work - Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, swift2

I have an Entity on my Core Data called `Users`. I want to adjust on click on Logout button, delete all data stored in `Users` entity.

I tried **this chunk (that I found from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1383645/4705339))but doesn't work** for a reason I couldn't figure out.

```
func deleteAll() {
        let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDel.managedObjectContext
        let coord = appDel.persistentStoreCoordinator

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")
//Also tried - let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: self.table!)

        let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)

        do {
            try coord.executeRequest(deleteRequest, withContext: context)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            debugPrint(error)
        }
    }
```

Logout Button:

```
@IBAction func logout(sender: AnyObject) {
      let user = User()
      user.deleteAll()
}
```

On `all()`, it is still returning data so `deleteAll()` doesn't delete anything.

**~`func all()` below is working~**

By the way, by using this line, I can access to all data stored in entity.

```
 let users = User()

 if let allUsers: AnyObject = users.all().result{
        print(allUsers.valueForKey("name"))
        print(allUsers.valueForKey("token"))
 }
```

and my `func all()` looks like this:

```
func all() ->(result: AnyObject?,error: NSError?){
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: self.table!)
    do {
        let fetched = try self.context?.executeFetchRequest(request)
        return (result: fetched, error: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        return (result: nil, error: error)
    }
```

Comment: I gather NSBatchDeleteRequest does not affect the context, so you might need to reset the context to clear the existing registered objects.

Comment: I did this by reseting simulator couple of times. Is this the way to do it?

Comment: Insert `context.reset()` after `try coord.executeRequest(deleteRequest, withContext: context)`.

Comment: Doesn't work either :/