# Most efficient way to delete all core objects in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

How could I delete all core objects without slowing down my app.

I have my app connected to a mysql database and every time I make an update on the database, the only way it updates on the app is if I delete all the core data and then reload it. However, this seems to take 30 seconds to do.

Comment: If you want to delete all the objects in your database, the easiest way is to remove your database and recreate it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077810/delete-reset-all-entries-in-core-data Else, for specific entities: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383598/core-data-quickest-way-to-delete-all-instances-of-an-entity

Comment: What is NSPersistentStore and NSPersistentStoreCoordinator?

Comment: Don't repost [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44392276/using-loop-and-deleteobject-taking-long-time-to-complete-objective-c). Add more context / information. Normally deleting objects is very fast. Which thread Is the code executed on?

Comment: Sorry, and on the main thread.

Comment: @King You're gonna need to post some code.  It is pretty hard to use CoreData without knowing what `NSPersistentStore`/`NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` are and that raises questions as to what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting objects is very fast! I realized my program was slow due to me adding images to the core data.