# CoreData Clear and Attributes data in a tableView

Tags: swift, tableview

I have looked around a lot and there doesn't seem to be a clear answer to this?
I have a table view controller where when I delete the cell and want it to remove the data show in a second table view controller which it is linked to via segue. So when deleted the core data attribute shapes should be cleared. With the code below I can only get it to delete one key pair in the attribute and not all.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        context!.delete(array[indexPath.row])
        array.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Notes>(entityName: "Notes")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "shape = %@")
        saveList()
        do {
            let shapes = try context!.fetch(fetchRequest)
            for shape in shapes {
                context!.delete(shape)
                let managedObjectData:NSManagedObject = shape as NSManagedObject
                context!.delete(managedObjectData)
            }
            try context!.save()
        } catch _ {
            // error handling
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Is there a simple way to clear an attribute of all its data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the fastest and correct way to achieve this is by using Coredata deletion rules. I guess in CoreData model you have a one to many relations - each color is related to some shape.
Therefore, in the Coredata editor go on the Identity Inspector and **set the relation's delete rule to `cascade`**. This means that once you delete a color, all of its corresponding shapes will be automatically deleted from the Perstistence store, no need to manually deleting them by looping over them!

Comment: Thank you this was so useful! Pointed me in the direction of this: https://cocoacasts.com/one-to-many-and-many-to-many-core-data-relationships/ which together solved my issue. Can also delete whole entities with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383598/core-data-quickest-way-to-delete-all-instances-of-an-entity