# Where is an application's Core Data sqlite database file located?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data

I would like to write a method that deletes my application's Core Data store, which I would follow by creating a new store. Is there a standard approach for doing this, and where is the database located in my application's sandbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You (perhaps unwittingly) have already told it where to go.  In Apple's Template code, the ApplicationDelegate automatically creates this store in the Application's Documents folder.  Take a look at the `-(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *) persistentStoreCoordinator` method in your ApplicationDelegate.

Comment: It sounds like it's enough to delete the file, set `persistentStoreCoordinator` to `nil` and run the app delegate's `persistentStoreCoordinator` method. Does that sound about right?

Comment: I've tried doing exactly that, and it doesn't quite work. By releasing your `persistentStoreCoordinator`, you invalidate the Managed Object Context's link. And the context doesn't take kindly to accepting a new coordinator. You could create a whole new context, but then all those connections break.  I'm sure there's a way to do it, but I gave up after futzing for a while and simply iterated through all my entities, deleting each one.

Comment: I don't think I can iterate through everything, since there can be many thousands of records. Anyone else have any thoughts?

Comment: One thing I didn't try that might be worth a shot: Remove the persistent store (with `removePersistentStore:error:`) and then delete the file, and then add the persistent store back again. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077810/delete-reset-all-entries-in-core-data/1222145#1222145