# How to delete all entries in Coredata with persistence store type NSInMemoryStoreType. Want it to happen in XCTest teardown

Tags: ios, core-data, xctest, persistent-storage

I am trying to unit test core data helper classes, so on my setUp function I create a core data db in memory by creating a `NSManagedObjectContext` using this code:

```
+ (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContextForTesting {
    static NSManagedObjectContext *_managedObjectContext = nil;
    if (_managedObjectContext == nil) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];

        NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Buddyup" withExtension:@"momd"];
        NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];

        [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSInMemoryStoreType configuration:nil URL:nil options:nil error:nil];

        [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:psc];

        _managedObjectContext = moc;
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

I can only find how to delete the core data entries if it's saved on disk. The usual answer is you need to delete the persistent store. So I tried to following
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375888/how-do-i-delete-all-objects-from-my-persistent-store-in-core-data/8467628#8467628) and tried:

```
+(void)flushDataBase
{
    NSError * error;

    NSManagedObjectContext * moc = [ManagedObjectContextTesting managedObjectContextForTesting];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator* psc = [moc persistentStoreCoordinator];
    [moc lock];
    for(NSPersistentStore *store in [psc persistentStores]) {
        [psc removePersistentStore:store error:nil];

         //this line will throw an error because store.URL looks something like "memory://12345"
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:store.URL.path error:&error]; 

    }
    [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSInMemoryStoreType configuration:nil URL:nil options:nil error:&error]; 
    [moc unlock];

}
```

The `flushDataBase` is called in the tearDown method. This doesn't work because when it hits the removeItemAtPath line, it throws an error
    `error: -[UserCoreDataTests testGetUserWithId_ReturnsNothing] : *** -[NSFileManager fileSystemRepresentationWithPath:]: nil or empty path argument`

This is because store.URL looks something "memory://12345" instead of "User://directory". That means the persistence storage URL is pointing to some place in memory. So how do I delete removing the store item in RAM?