# How to completely clear out a Core Data model?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data, ios4

How I could completely clear out EVERYTHING in a Core Data model i.e remove all objects for all entities?

I will be using the code to clear out the saved history in a the model.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is another way to do...

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
            NSFetchRequest * allMovies = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
            [allMovies setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Movies" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
            [allMovies setIncludesPropertyValues:NO]; //only fetch the managedObjectID

            NSError * error = nil;
            NSArray * movies = [context executeFetchRequest:allMovies error:&error];
            //error handling goes here
            for (NSManagedObject * movie in movies) {
                [context deleteObject:movie];
            }
            NSError *saveError = nil;
            [context save:&saveError];
```

It will clear all the objects.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the .sqlite DB Core Data creates (it's probably stored on your /Documents directory) and get your app to re-create it.

Comment: You specify the URL for the persistent store when you create the persistent store, so you should already know where the file is. You can use NSFileManager's -removeItemAtPath:error: method to delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good answer to this question.

[Delete/Reset all entries in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077810/delete-reset-all-entries-in-core-data/3011852#3011852)

Then just make sure to re-create the store.