# Clear a whole Core Data using NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, nsmanagedobjectcontext, persistent-storage

I am using Core Data in my app,

and maybe my users wants to delete all the NSManagedObjects that they once saved,

So is there a quick method of NSManagedObjectContext that can do this, I mean, clear the whole persistent store, or in another word,delete all objects of every entity, so there's no actual objects (except entities) in core data?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete/Reset all entries in Core Data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077810/delete-reset-all-entries-in-core-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either delete everything entity-by-entity or clear the store file itself.

See this solution: [Delete/Reset all entries in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077810/delete-reset-all-entries-in-core-data)

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the file and recreate your persistent store, then everything is nice and empty.