# Delete all Core Data data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have the above CoreData scheme. How can i delete everything in it ? Is there an easy and quick way ?

[image]

**Update:**

Ok i try this

```
func flushDatabase() {
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext{
        moc.lock()

        if let stores = persistentStoreCoordinator?.persistentStores as? [NSPersistentStore] {
            for store in stores {
                persistentStoreCoordinator?.removePersistentStore(store, error: nil)
                if let path = store.URL?.path {
                    NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(path, error: nil)
                }
            }
        }

        moc.unlock()



    }
}
```

But how i recreate the persistenStoreCoordinator ?

**Update 2**

```
 class func deleteAllMinigames(context:NSManagedObjectContext) {
        context.lock()
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Minigame")
//        fetchRequest.includesSubentities = true
//        fetchRequest.includesPropertyValues = false
        var error: NSError?
        if let items = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [Minigame]{
            for item in items {
                if item.validateForDelete(&error){
                    context.deleteObject(item)
                }else{
                    println(error?.localizedDescription)
                }

            }
        }
        context.unlock()

    }
```

When i trying to delete all minigames i get this. I tried to make all delete to rules to cacsade but its not working

```
*Optional("The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1560.)")
Optional("The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1560.)")
Optional("The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1560.)")
Optional("The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1560.)")
Optional("The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1560.)")
Optional("The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1560.)")*
```

Comment: The "Related" section on the right shows some similar questions (with answers). Which one did you try?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete/Reset all entries in Core Data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077810/delete-reset-all-entries-in-core-data)

Comment: Have you tried ctrl+click in all the tables and press `return`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means there's a mandatory property has been assigned nil. Either in your *.xcodatamodel check the "optional" box or when you are saving to the managedObjectContext make sure that your properties are filled in.

If you're getting further errors after changing your code to suit the two requirements try cleaning your build and delete the application from your iPhone Simulator/iPhone device. Your model change may conflict with the old model implementation.

Edit:

I almost forgot here's all the error codes that Core Data spits out: [Core Data Constants Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Miscellaneous/CoreData_Constants/index.html) I had trouble with this before and I realised I unchecked the correct optional box. Such trouble finding out the problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `NSFileManager` to remove the persistent data store file and setup the core data stack again.

Answer (score 1):

Since every entity is somehow connected to your `Minigame`, you can set the delete rules to cascade from there on the relationships, and just simply delete all your `Minigames`. It would automatically delete the rest, using somethinf like this:

```
+ (void)deleteAllMinigamesInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Minigame"];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL];
    for (Minigame *game in fetchedObjects) {
        [context deleteObject:game];
    }
    [context save:NULL];
}
```

**Edit:**

Between `Multiplechoice` and `Answer` set the rule only to nullify, because you have a loop there which might fail otherwise. How did you set the delete rules for the rest? The `cascade` only has to be unidirectional, so for example in `Minigame` for the relationship called `coupon` you need `cascade`, but for the inverse relationship (`minigame` in `Coupon`) you only need `nullify`