# NSBatchDeleteRequest in Swift 3 for iOS 10 only?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So, migrating my code to `Swift 3` has me a bit stuck. It seems `NSBatchDeleteRequest` requires `iOS 10` now? The only way I could make the code build is with the following snippet:

```
func removeAllChargerData(){
    // Remove all charging data from persistent storage
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = ChargerPrimary.fetchRequest()
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "ChargerPrimary", in: self.secondMoc)
    fetchRequest.entity = entity
    let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)

    do {
        try self.secondMoc.execute(deleteRequest)
    } catch {
        let deleteError = error as NSError
        NSLog("\(deleteError), \(deleteError.localizedDescription)")
    }

}
```

However, a warning shows up indicating that `fetchRequest()` is only available in `iOS 10` and newer. If I define the `fetchRequest` the following way, I get an error because it expect the `fetchRequest` to has a `NSFetchRequestResult` argument type:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<ChargerPrimary>(entityName: "ChargerPrimary")
```

Comment: i have the same confusion too. Unfortunately no documentation from apple on that - guess they were too busy delivering all these new neat features, so understandable.

Comment: Still, its a pretty significant feature that's not seemingly left completely broken. :/ And considering the amount of time Swift 3 and Xcode 8 spent in beta, I cant really see it's an understandable omission.

Comment: Your issue is just the generic fetch request, not the batch deletion as such

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to specify the correct type for the generic:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ChargerPrimary")
```

Comment: But can you use that with NSBatchDeleteRequest in iOS 9? I suspect the answer is now, which is the actual question here: How to use NSBatchDeleteRequest in Swift 3 with iOS 9.

Comment: @Zygote I have just tested on the iOS9.3 simulator, and it seems to work fine.  What problems are you having with it?

Answer (score 2):

Probably It's also working for me in IOS 10

```
 let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ChargerPrimary")
 let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
```

You should use fetchrequest like this without giving specific type to varible

Here is [DEMO](http://www.learncoredata.com/nsbatchdeleterequest-in-ios-9/) For IOS 9

Comment: Yeah, If you want documentation then I will provide you a link

Comment: @Zygote Did you get you want from that link ?

Comment: I'll have to verify it later, but I suspect the link you posted is for Swift 2 since it's from 2015. Just to clarify: NSBatchDeleteRequest worked fine for me with Swift 2, but in Swift 3 I can only seem to get it to work for iOS 10.