# How to prevent ios app from loading previous core data stored on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want the app to pull new objects every time it is loaded (start-up) and not retrieve old information stored, how would I do this effectively?

Comment: Delete your database at start? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077810/delete-reset-all-entries-in-core-data ?

Comment: So delete it in the program start method?